# parsing tab delimited values from text file to variables

Tags: python, parsing, pandas, csv

Hello I've been struggling with this problem, I'm trying to iterate over rows and select data from them and then assign them to variables. this is the first time I'm using pandas and I'm not sure how to select the data

```
reader = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep="\t" ,lineterminator='\r', usecols=[0,1,2,9,10],)

for row in reader:
    print(row)
    #id_number = row[0]
    #name = row[2]
    #ip_address = row[1]
    #latitude = row[9]
```

and this is the output from the row that I want to assign to the variables:

```
050000

129.240.228.138

planetlab2.simula.no

59.93
```

Edit: Perhaps this is not a problem for pandas but for general Python. I am fairly new to python and what I'm trying to achieve is to parse tab separated file line by line and assign data to the variables and print them in one loop.

this is the input file sample:

```
050263  128.2.211.113   planetlab-1.cmcl.cs.cmu.edu NA  US  Allegheny County    Pittsburgh  http://www.cs.cmu.edu/  Carnegie Mellon University  40.4446 -79.9427    unknown
050264  128.2.211.115   planetlab-3.cmcl.cs.cmu.edu NA  US  Allegheny County    Pittsburgh  http://www.cs.cmu.edu/  Carnegie Mellon University  40.4446 -79.9427    unknown
```

Comment: What do you mean assign to variables? Individual data points or whole columns? And why do either? Each are contained in a dataframe and can be referenced with `.loc`, `.ix`, or `[]`.

Comment: What I meant that in the input file the data is tab separated on each line(id\taddress\tname\tlatitude etc.). I want to iterate line by line and assign the data to the variables

Comment: What does *reader* look like? And what is your desired output? Not quite understanding as pandas can read tab-delimited files. And columns not rows are assigned.

Comment: my desired output is basically what I said to iterate line by line though the file and assing the data from each line to variables. and then print them. This has to be done in a loop. as for Reader thats my mistake, the variable should be called df.

Comment: Still do not get *why*. You may not need pandas but general python. Each column in a pandas Dataframe is a pandas Series which is one type (integer, string, datetime) which can be your *variable*. To assign by lines combines different types and no longer will you have series to run various functions. What do you hope to do with such variables? Please edit your post with more information (input and output) as this is becoming the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general workflow you're describing is: you want to read in a csv, find a row in the file with a certain ID, and unpack all the values from that row into variables. This is simple to do with pandas.

It looks like the CSV file has at least 10 columns in it. Providing the usecols arg should filter out the columns that you're not interested in, and read_csv will ignore them when loading into the pandas DataFrame object (which you've called reader).

Steps to do what you want:

1. Read the data file using `pd.read_csv()`. You've already done this, but I recommend calling this variable df instead of reader, as read_csv returns a DataFrame object, not a Reader object. You'll also find it convenient to use the names argument to read_csv to assign column names to the dataframe. It looks like you want `names=['id', 'ip_address', 'name', 'latitude','longitude']` to get those as columns. (Assuming col10 is longitude, which makes sense that 9,10 would be lat/long pairs)
2. Query the dataframe object for the row with that ID that you're interested in. There are a variety of ways to do this. One is [using the query syntax](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html). Hard to know why you want that specific row without more details, but you can look up more information about index lookups in pandas. Example: `row = df.query("id == 50000")`
3. Given a single row, you want to extract the row values into variables. This is easy if you've assigned column names to your dataframe. You can treat the row as a dictionary of values. E.g. `lat = row['lat']` `lon = row['long]`

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the answer, just wanted to add that there are no headings in my input file, so I want to go through all the tab separated lines (each line contains all the data I want) and parse them into the variables so I can add the variable to a map object which represents a geographical map in every iteration of the loop.. so basically: 1.read line, 2. parse data, 3.print the value.. and then the same again

Comment: @FrantisekFaraks - you see what just happened? Your lack of information of total problem was misinterpreted and this answer does not work for you. Please show us your input file and desired output for reproducible example and larger context (the X not Y of XY problem).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `iterrows()`:

```
df = pandas.read_csv(file_path, sep=',')
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    value = row['col_name']
```

Or if you want to access by index of the column:

```
df = pandas.read_csv(file_path, sep=',')
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    value = row.ix[0]
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer, I have question, this why is the index variable needed ?

Comment: `index` is essentially for the row index. For the example above, it is not necessary, but depending on your use case you may need it.

Answer (score 0):

Are the values you need to add the same for each row, or does it require processing the value to determine the value of the addition? If it is consistent you can apply this sum simply using pandas to do a matrix operation on the dataset. If it requires processing row by row, the above solution is the correct one for sure. If it is a table of variables that must be added row by row, you can do that by dumping them all into a column aligned with your dataset, do the addition by row using pandas, and simply print out the complete dataframe. Assume you have three columns to add, which you put into a new column[e].

df['e'] = df.a + df.b + df.d

or, if it is a constant:

df['e'] = df.a + df.b + {constant}

Then drop the columns you don't need (ex df['a'] and df['b'] in the above)

Obviously, then, if you need to calculate based on unique values for each row, put the values into another column and sum as above.